# Optimal Resolution not updated in youtube application

Tags: cobalt

We are currently using Cobalt13.111497 version for our YouTube Playback. In this Cobalt version, when we try to play the video ID of '1w4zhAtBl3k' and 'Tqh-etL9ehu', optimal resolution has not been updated for Codec of VP9(242) & opus(251). For our checking, we have ommitted the VP9 by `IsTypeSupported()` and supported the `IsTypeSupported()` as H264 codec then optimal resolution has been updated as expected. Also we have observed the same issue behaviour in Google Chrome. Whether this issue is specific to this Cobalt version or problem in YouTube itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was found and resolved. This issue occurred due to framewidth & frameheight was not updated. After updating that in client layer, Problem has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately it will be hard to say for certain what the issue is, as Cobalt 13.111497 is an old version of Cobalt, and also unsupported.  Please consider using the latest version of Cobalt from the 19.lts.1+ branch ( https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+log/19.lts.1+ ), which is currently 19.lts.1.183273.  Please let us know if you are able to reproduce the issue in the latest build.

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply. We have updated the current resolution as expected(Natural Size). And we have doubt that whether optimal resolution expects anything from device or optimal resolution is based on application authoring.